# get posts function not working wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have developed a wordpress website in which I have used `get_posts()` function .Few days ago I found the wordpress was updated on my server.
Since then my `get_posts()` function is not working.
I have used `get_posts()` without any argument still it is not working.
I have used some other functions like `get_users()` which are working fine.
Right now I have `Version 4.1.1`

```
    $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'offset' => 0,
            'category_name' => 'press',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_type' => 'post',             
            'post_status' => 'publish',
           'suppress_filters' => true
    );

        $posts_array = get_posts();
```

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($posts_array)`?

Comment: `post_date` should be `date`. Most probably your posts post_status changed, that is why you do not get posts

Comment: are you want your data by category .. you mention above 'category name'

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your `$args` to `get_posts()`. There may be other issues, but at least do that.

`$posts_array = get_posts($args);`